# Why does swiperjs grid doesnt work when i use breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

```
<Swiper
    grid={{
      rows: 2,
    }}
    spaceBetween={30}
    pagination={{
      clickable: true,
    }}
    modules={[Grid, Pagination]}
    breakpoints={{
      0:{
        slidesPerView: 2,
      },
      576: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
      },
      992: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
      }
    }}
    className="mySwiper"
  >
```

the grid row becomes 1 when the screen is getting smaller, but when i refresh the page it become normal

[this is when the screen is 1440](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgemQ.png)
[this is when the screen is below 992](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBo5S.png)
[but when i refresh the page, it goes back to normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7lTn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `rows: 2` in breakpoints too.

```
<Swiper
grid={{
  rows: 2,
}}
spaceBetween={30}
pagination={{
  clickable: true,
}}
modules={[Grid, Pagination]}
breakpoints={{
  0:{
    slidesPerView: 2,
    rows: 2,
  },
  576: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    rows: 2,
  },
  992: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    rows: 2,
  }
}}
className="mySwiper"
```

> 